# My self hosted font on Wordpress are not loading

Tags: wordpress, fonts, wordpress-theming, self-hosting, wpengine

The font is uploaded into the directory of the child theme and the stylesheet is being called correctly, but the fonts files themselves aren't being applied according to my css declarations. I created a font.css file and I have this code in it.

```
    @import url("https://fast.fonts.net/lt/1.css?apiType=css&c=aac5a6bc-2331-43a2-9ced-f4fc346c41dd&fontids=5672533");
@font-face{
    font-family: "Alternate Gothic";
    src:url("fonts/ee6f4110-f8b2-468e-a988-889fd8f73ca2.woff2") format("woff2"),url("https://sunnydaykcdev.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/essence-pro/fonts/d9bf39bd-b8df-4cec-8f40-aa72a922ed70.woff") format("woff");
}
```

/*
This CSS resource incorporates links to font software which is the valuable copyrighted property of Monotype and/or its suppliers. You may not attempt to copy, install, redistribute, convert, modify or reverse engineer this font software. Please contact Monotype with any questions regarding Web Fonts: https://www.linotype.com
*/

The stlye.css and the fonts folder are at the same level in the directory, so I'm pretty sure I have the path right. Please let me know if you have any tips!

Comment: Your pointing at a path for a URL property. Try changing fonts/ to the url of the file.

Comment: Hi Jessica, glad it worked. Could you accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pointing at a path for a URL property. Try changing fonts/ to the url of the file.